# wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a PDF from a Telegram BOT.When I select a file from my server , it shows this message:

```
Client error: `POST https://api.telegram.org/botXXXX/sendDocument` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:\n {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}\
```

But when I choose from other servers, it works fine!

my file is this directory :

```
http://109.169.XX.XX:7070/pdfs/sample.pdf
```

Should the server port be 80?

code :

```
$data=[
        'chat_id' =>'YYYYY' ,
        'caption' =>'test' ,
        'document'=>"http://109.169.xx.xx:7070/pdfs/sample.pdf",
        ];


$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $token . '/sendDocument';

$client= new \GuzzleHttp\Client([]);
$result  = client->post( $url,['form_params'=>$data]);
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @Evert  code added

Comment: What mime type does the `.pdf` return when opening it? (`Content-Type` header)

Comment: @Evert MIME Type: application/pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem has been resolved

I had to transfer my code from Port 7070 to port 80

For example, my PDF file address is :

```
http://109.169.XX.XX/pdfs/sample.pdf
```

I suggest if you encounter this problem, Be sure your code to run on port 80, and as far as possible use the domain instead of IP